# Combining a SELECT statement with a DB function using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I wanted to know if there was a way to inject the results from a SELECT statement into an Oracle DB function using only one transaction and SQLAlchemy. I'm looking to improve my code writing and understanding of SQLAlchemy.

I currently have it working with 2 transactions.

```
(
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3,
    column_4,
    column_5,
    column_6,
) = session.execute(
    select(
        Table1.column_1,
        Table1.column_2,
        Table1.column_3,
        Table1.column_4,
        Table2.column_5,
        Table3.column_6,
    )
    .join(Table3, Table3.column == Table1.column)
    .join(Table2, Table2.column == Table1.column)
    .filter(Table1.id == id)
).first()

return session.scalar(
    select(
        func.get_path(
            column_1,
            column_2,
            column_3,
            column_4,
            column_5,
            column_6,
        )
    )
)
```